# Wiped my HDD with Proxmox 8. Can it be recovered?

Tags: hard-drive, partitioning, recovery

I was using Proxmox 8, I have a bunch of HDD's to setup. One is a secondary HDD for my Windows - the Windows OD is on a SSD, but I use the HDD for bulk.

In Proxmox I clicked "wipe disk" - and clicked "ok" cause I know what I'm doing... was the wrong drive! Now i need to know if I can get the partition information recovered with some tools? I ran testdisk which found some stuff but it said that partitions are not recoverable.

Is there any hope?

Comment: since they chose to use the word "wipe", that kind of implies that the data was overwritten. if that is the case you won't be able to recover data from it. how long did the wipe take?

Comment: done in an instant. i guess it just nuked the partition info etc?? I'm currently running AOMEI which is scanning the disk - so far that claims to have found 499 partitions?!

Comment: If for just a minute, some data *might* be recoverable, as you doing... but in a piecemeal fashion. However, that recovery, *combined with the last disk image* you made, you should lose very little.

Comment: ironically, the hdd's I need to setup were for making a backup storage so I can make image backups of the machine, I wiped the disk before getting it backed up lol